# MassTransit RequestResponse sample move responses to skipped queue on .Net core

Tags: rabbitmq, .net-core, masstransit

I ported MassTransit [Sample-RequestResponse sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse) to .net core. Did some small modifications to the sample in order to host the .net core service. Although the service can receive the requests, the response is not received by the client and end up in ignore_skipped queue on rabbitmq. However, in some executions I receive a response to the first request I sent, and fails there after. What is the root cause for this? How can we implement RequestResponse pattern on MassTransit

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: 61000000-5d62-0015-cafc-08d4d8a6a3f2) ---> MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: 61000000-5d62-0015-cafc-08d4d8a6a3f2
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.RequestClient`2.<Request>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<<Main>b__1>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Since .NET Core version is in pre-release, I suggest opening a github issue instead of aksing here.

Comment: Done #953 . thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an bug with how the request/response exchange and queue was created. I have patched the code and my pull request [#954](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/59ec6bd32f4f0255c349d22951a36d4f6586d04b) was merged.

Comment: Can't believe it.. I wasted 2 hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: @gerjvr although a new queue is created I still doesn't get the response, using the latest nuget "4.0.0.1248-develop" , Does it another bug?

Comment: @AviramFireberger I just tried with the new packages and it working as expected.

Comment: Sorry about that,
I notice that I forget to start the bus to create a queue for the return object